# MySQL: Необходимо сделать, чтобы хранимая процедура вывела строки, в которых есть совпадения

Tags: mysql, хранимые-процедуры

Необходима Ваша помощь. В хранимой процедуре удается вывести варианты, когда строка в переменной locality полностью похожа на строку, а мне надо только чтобы была возможность поиска определенного слова в этой переменной, а я с синтаксической точки зрения не знаю как это сделать.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE proc26(IN locality VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
SELECT id_t, marsh, cost, trans, eat, date_of_dispatch, time_of_dispatch, DATE_ADD(date_of_dispatch, INTERVAL ttime DAY) AS day_of_stay FROM timetable
INNER JOIN information ON information.id_p = timetable.id_p
WHERE marsh LIKE locality; 
END; //
```

Comment: вопрос-то о синтаксисе команды select, и абсолютно не понятно, какое к вопросу отношение имеет хранимая процедура.

Comment: `like concat('%', locality, '%')`

Comment: @teran спасибо большое, вы мне очень помогли